# Two methods, do the same thing, in different ways

Tags: c#

Hi I'm new to programming and I got this code:

```
public void Print(out string dataToPrint)
{
    //code....
    dataToPrint = "some text here"
}
```

And:

```
public string dataToPrint()
{
    //code
    return "some text here"
}
```

Which one will be used today, and which example will a professional programmer will use and what is the fastest in terms of performance?

Comment: If you have two horses and you want to know which is the fastest then you should **race** them. Don't ask us to guess or work it out for you.

Comment: The performance difference, if any, should be so so small you will never notice it unless running your code in a very tight loop.

Comment: I'd should care about legibility more than performance, unless you have a **measured** performance issue and `out` is the only thing you can optimize there (after almost everything else...). In short: yes, there might be a TINY (micro? nano?) performance penalty but it's that small that hardly you will see any gain. Code for clarity, optimize for performance if and when required.

Comment: Write code that is more readable. Optimize only what needs to be optimized.

Comment: when you want to return more than one value from a method , `out` is the one of them , and it does not affect on performance . if you have just one value to return dont use out for that

Comment: if you have a code and you are note sure about its performace you can use `Codereview.stackexchange.com `

Comment: Tested on my laptop, Looping 10,000,000 times return was faster by a total of 140-160 milliseconds than out This means that even in a very tight loop, the performance difference is totally negligible. You can see [the code I've used for testing on rextester](http://rextester.com/CIXN76860), where the difference was considerably smaller - only 3-7 ms!

Comment: Passing a value back to the caller by assigning to a variable passed by reference makes me think back to the times of Pascal and Modula-2 where this style was used a lot. In terms of composability, you should prefer a return value where possible. As to the performance aspect, we have enough evidence by now to show that it should not make a difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In terms of performance there is nearly no difference, you can try it by running the each method inside a loop and test the time each can take, or use [benchmark.net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) .

I tried it with Benchmark.net using following code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Print(out string dataToPrint)
    {
        dataToPrint = "some text here";
    }

    public string Print()
    {
        return "some text here";
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void one()
    {
        string data;
        Print(out data);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void two()
    {
        Print();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Class1>();
    }
}
```

And the result was :
[image: result of benchmark]
As you can see the difference is too small, so you shouldn't consider it in your case, but I prefer the second form for readability, however, for other cases try using same procedure and find out.

Comment: How do you know that there is nearly no difference? That the JIT will do the necessary optimizations (and what does that mean)?

Comment: thanks for your feedback

Comment: No, truly, this site isn't about posting opinion pieces when hard facts can be produced. How can you justify your answer?

Comment: You can see the updated answer